# Adding multiple titles do C3.js donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

Is there any way to include multiple titles inside my donut chart? I am using c3.js to create the chart below:

[image: Donut Chart]

I want to add one more field inside the chart, below "Days" called Score.

Below is the code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            columns:[
                     ['First Part ', 54],
                     ['Second Part ', ' '+ 24],
                     ['Third Part ', ' ' + 22]
            ],
            type: 'donut',
            colors: {
                data1: '#ff0000',
                data2: '#00ff00',
                data3: '#0040ff'
                },                                      
            },
            donut: {
               expand: false,
               title: 'Days 28'
                //want to add 'Score' to the title so it appears on the line below "Days 28"
            }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This title in the center of the donut belongs to a class called `c3-chart-arcs-title`. So, you can simply append a `tspan` to it:

```
d3.select(".c3-chart-arcs-title")
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", 16)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text("Score");
```

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/0vuombw4/
(PS: this fiddle is not mine, I just used it to append the extra text).

Comment: As another example there is this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ew5dDA1R3biXnMp80LDd?p=preview